# How can I add a block of text to google calendar events underneath the event description that neither the organizer or participants can edit?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-workspace

The company I'm building this for has total staff of 150 people, around 75 sales staff.

My Objective = Company wide compliance through creating a disclaimer attached to every calendar event.

Tech Stack = Scheduleonce > Calendar event creation | Google calendar > Busy time retrieval, event descriptions, location of the meeting etc.

What I've Tried

1. Google Apps Script to attach a document displaying the disclaimer, however this is a bit redundant as the disclaimer is visible on our website.
2. Google apps script automation that writes the disclaimer at the bottom of the calendar event. This would allow the event organizer to edit the disclaimer, which would be a liability for all intent & purposes with compliance.

The intended outcome is meant to reflect the "General Advice Notice" that's at the bottom of the image attached.

Comment: If you could periodically detect and fix a disclaimer that was tampered with every hour, is that an acceptable amount of liability? If not, what is an acceptable interval duration?